# IBM Connections Files CMIS: Unable to find object at path /My Files

Tags: lotus, cmis, ibm-connections, dotcmis, opencmis

I am using [DotCMIS](http://chemistry.apache.org/dotnet/dotcmis.html) with no problem to connect to Alfresco and FileNet.

I [registered](https://greenhouse.lotus.com/gh_next/lotusgreenhouserequests.nsf/MainDocumentSelf?openForm) for an [IBM Connections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Connections) account, added a few files via the web interface, and tried to connect to its CMIS endpoint https://greenhouse.lotus.com/files/basic/cmis/my/servicedoc

`GetRepositories` on this URL gives one repository, which in turn contain the two folders below:

```
My Files
My Folders
```

But when I run `GetObjectByPath("/My Files")` in the same repository, I get:

```
DotCMIS.Exceptions.CmisObjectNotFoundException was unhandled
 Message=Not Found
 Source=DotCMIS
 ErrorContent=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><lcmis:error xmlns:lcmis="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/cmis"><lcmis:code>objectNotFound</lcmis:code><lcmis:message>EJPVJ9023E: Unable to find object at path /My Files</lcmis:message><lcmis:userAction></lcmis:userAction></lcmis:error>
```

What does IBM Connections say `Unable to find object at path /My Files` despite `My Files` being a folder at the root of the repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cmis:name property ("My Files", "My Folers") is localized.  A non-English user would get different cmis:name property values for these two objects.

To fetch children from these resources, you need to build the path using the cmis:path property returned on each object or construct the path relative to its parent using the cmisra:pathSegment.

For example, the cmis:object for the resource labeled "My Files" in your scenario has the following:

```
<cmis:propertyString propertyDefinitionId="cmis:path"
 localName="cmis_path" displayName="Path" queryName="cmis:path">
 <cmis:value>/files</cmis:value>
</cmis:propertyString>
```

So to actually fetch the user's files, the path to call is the following:

```
GetObjectByPath("/files")
```

And to fetch the user's folders, the path to call is the following:

```
GetObjectByPath("/collections")
```

The net is to ensure you build paths using the cmisra:pathSegment or the cmis:path property, and not the cmis:name as this may not be valid in all scenarios (i.e. if the repository has same name siblings, etc.).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! `GetObjectByPath("/files")` fails with `System.ArgumentException "Object type must have property defintions!" at DotCMIS.Client.Impl.AbstractCmisObject.Initialize` [*sic*]. I also tried `GetObjectByPath("/snx:files")` which fails with `CmisObjectNotFoundException "EJPVJ9023E: Unable to find object at path /snx:files" at DotCMIS.Binding.AtomPub.AbstractAtomPubService.Read`, I guess this one is normal behavior. I will try a few things with "/files" and come back to you later.

Comment: Your tip about localized names has helped me a lot, thanks! I still get an exception, but I guess it is a different problem, so I created a DotCMIS issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CMIS-593